# Problemas con menú al actualizar bootstrap 4

Tags: ajax, bootstrap-4

Tengo un menú dinámico que reside en `_Layout.cshtml`, el cual obtiene sus datos a través de `ajax`, al momento de cargar la página.

El tema es que al actualizar a bootstrap4 el menú que se desplegaba horizontalmente ahora queda contraído en una especie de `button`, y al presionarlo, se despliega hacia abajo.

Estoy usando como items del menu elementos del tipo

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
```

Que se construyen dinámicamente en la función `ajax`.

Porque pasa esto? he buscado en la documentación de `bootstrap`, pero no indican cambios en esos niveles.

aca pongo el codigo de una plantilla basica generada en asp.net mvc

```html
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, @User.Identity.Name!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Comment: Puede que su menú sea `navbar-toggleable` igual creo que sería necesario añadir el código de menú.

Comment: mira, hice una prueba con una plantilla de asp,net mvc. puse el codigo en la pregunta.

Comment: Recomiendo leer la [Documentación](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#supported-content) , la clase que emplea está definida para **ocultar** el contenido. y desplegar con el botón. o sea está documentado. :)

Answer (score 0):

Me paso lo mismo actualizando los paquetes a las ultimas versiones en un ASP.NET con VB.NET.

Lo que hice fue lo siguiente:
La línea en el _layout si el proyecto es MVC o en el Master.page si un proyecto WebForms.
`<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">`

Eliminar la clase **collapse**, esto hace que funcione como estaba funcionando, si usas el sitio en dispositivos moviles esto no oculta el menu por primera vez lo coloca apilado hacia abajo, sin embargo luego que presiones el botón de hamburguesa funciona de manera correcta.
Por lo menos este es el comportamiento que me ha dado a mi.  Si logro mas cosas aqui las colocare.

Feliz Coding!!!